# Play audio on page load

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to play audio on the page load. I have a website that sends a notification to users and plays a notification sound. Sometimes the notification is sent before user interaction with the browser, in this case, the sound is not getting played.

I am using the following code:

```
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
        const audio = new Audio(site_url+"/audio/pristine.mp3");
        const source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        audio.play();
```

Please guide me what can be done about this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide    IOW: There is no silver bullet here,  but the easiest option if your users are on Chrome -> The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.

Comment: @Keith Thank you for your response but it is not possible to ask every user to add the site on the homescreen.